# asp.net with C# in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net

i have designed a form using required validation that have two buttons Save and reset. save button are working properly but when i clicked on reset button it also checks the validation but not doing the another task. how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the button skip validation by adding the attribute `CausesValidation="false"` to your .aspx page on the button markup.